# why the counter MAIN.backend_unhealthy in varnishstat don't work, when use libvmod-dynamic?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

i'm using varnish 6.5.1, and libvmod-dynamic, as now we move to the cloud (aws). and when i shut my backend, varnish detect the unhealthy backend, switch to grace mode etc.. BUT, the counter
MAIN.backend_unhealthy  stay at 0.

is there anything to do to correct that ?

thanks

here it is, a short version of the vcl to test:
`code`

```
vcl 4.1;

import std;
import querystring;
import dynamic;



/**
 * Drupal backend.
 */
backend drupal {
    .host = "";
    .port = "";
/*
.probe = {
        .request =
          "HEAD /scripts/utility_checkStatus.php?status=files HTTP/1.0"
          "User-Agent: Varnish Health Probe";
        .timeout = 1s;
        .interval = 500ms;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 8;
    }
*/
}


probe drupalprobe {
        .request =
          "HEAD /scripts/utility_checkStatus.php?status=files HTTP/1.0"
          "User-Agent: Varnish Health Probe";
        .timeout = 1s;
        .interval = 500ms;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 8;
    }


sub vcl_init {

new ddir = dynamic.director(
                           port = "50011",
                          probe= drupalprobe ,
ttl = 20s,

);

}


/**
 * Called when a client request is received
 */
sub vcl_recv {
    // Check previous errors.


      set req.backend_hint =  ddir.backend("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");

    // Health Check - add ping uri to test Varnish status
    if (req.method == "GET" && req.url ~ "/healthCheck.html") {
            return(synth(200,"OK"));
     }

}
```

`code`

set req.backend_hint =  ddir.backend("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");  --> can simply replace the x by an ip of a backend.

when start all is ok:
0 Backend_health - ddir(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50011) Still healthy 4---X-RH 10 8 10 0.002815 0.003033 "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"

i shut the backend:
0 Backend_health - ddir(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50011) Still sick -------- 0 8 10 0.000000 0.003287 "Open error 111 (Connection refused)"

switch to grace mode but:
MAIN.backend_unhealthy            0         0.00 Backend conn. not attempted

it's stuck to 0

i notice that this counter is increasing:
VBE.boot.ddir(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50011).fail_econnrefused

Comment: Did you configure a health probe for these dynamic backends? Varnish needs a probe to determine backend health. As you mentioned, this has no impact on grace.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention that, indeed i configured a health probe. Even with that, the counter is stuck to 0

Comment: Can you please share your VCL? I'd like to simulate the problem.

Comment: done, i edit the main message with much information

Comment: My advice would be to open up an issue with Nils who developed this VMOD, but I notice you already have: https://github.com/nigoroll/libvmod-dynamic/issues/72.

Keep us updated.